# Partnership Visa in EU, move to UK

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas, us-citizens, eu

I've been looking but can't find the answer to this question.  I have a partnership visa in Czech Republic with a UK partner (I'm American). We would like to move to the UK. As we have been living in the Czech Republic, we don't meet the funding requirements for the UK partnership visa. As we are on an EU partnership visa, can we use this to move to the UK?

Comment: How long have you been living and working together in the Czech Republic? Long enough to have activated your partner's treaty rights? (ideally 6+ months). If so, you should be fine to go down the [Surinder Singh route](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/surinder-singh)

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify, putting on hold.